# (IOS / Android) app to app push notifications (without using server)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I'm looking to build a set of apps that would utilise push notifications to other users in the vicinity.

had a look at urbanairship and xtify but am not sure if its possible to do app to app push notificitions without use of an intermediary server?

the push notifications would be preset with some local data pulled from the app itself

Any advice / suggestions appreciated

thx,
Ken

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get this done with [pubnub](http://pubnub.com). You'll notice that your (Android or iOS) *clients* can be broadcasters (if you allow them) as well as receivers so it should do what you need. They also offer a generous (enough) free mode for you to get going.

Comment: We'll have a check with that. So far, we haven't got to stage where we start implementing but its on the cards